# Passing C# attributes to other attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, custom-attributes

is it possible to pass C# attributes (annotations?) from one declaration to another? I am trying to get the following to work:

Observe the following hypothetical code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Something
{
  [XmlArray(ElementName = "Array")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Item")]
  public List<UnpleasantlyNamedItem> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

now, this will serialize and deserialize like a charm. It works wonderfully well. However for our project I need something like this.

```
[Serializable]
public class EvolvableList<T> where T : GameObject
{
  [XmlArray(ElementName = "Add")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = I want my "AddItemName" attribute here)]
  public List<T> Add { get; private set; }

  [XmlArray(ElementName = "Edit")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = I want my "EditItemName" attribute here)]
  public List<ObjectTransformation<T>> Edit { get; private set; }

  [XmlArray(ElementName = "Remove")]
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = I want my "RemoveItemName" attribute here)]
  public List<ObjectReference<T>> Remove { get; private set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class UpgradeLevel
{
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Level")
  public int Level { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "Models")]
  [ExtXmlEvolvableList(AddItemName = "Model", EditItemName = "Model", RemoveItemName = "Model")]
  public EvolvableList<Model> Models { get; private set; }

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sprites")]
  [ExtXmlEvolvableList(AddItemName = "Sprite", EditItemName = "Sprite", RemoveItemName = "Sprite")]
  public EvolvableList<Sprite> Sprites { get; private set; }
}
```

Is this possible? I tried googling it, but I am not sure how to phrase the query to say for sure. I am new to the concept of annotations, since I mainly write software in C/C++.

I already tried letting the serializer decide on the name itself by ommitting the [XmlArrayItem] attribute. This gives me a rather clumsy "ReferenceOfModel" element name. This in itself is not a big problem. However it becomes a problem when deserializing it. That simply doesn't seem to work as well as when I use the [XmlArrayItem] attribute. It also may pose a problem later on when I am using different Xml serializers/deserializers when I have c++/java/objective c clients.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating a constant, no, you cannot do that.

The code that reads those attributes could be changed to use one inside the other but there is nothing built into C# or .NET that allows this.

With constant:

```
private const string AddItemName = "Add";
[XmlArray(ElementName = AddItemName)]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "I want my " + AddItemName + " attribute here")]
public List<T> Add { get; private set; }
```